# C++ confusing compilation errors

Tags: c++

Below is the compilation errors I'm getting and the header/cpp files that go with em. If anyone has a few minutes and a better eye at catching something that I can't, I would love them forever. This goes back to an a3main.cpp to be tested, so if you need that file fir reference as well just give me a shout. Thanks again!

```
a3.cpp: In constructor 'disk::disk(int, const char*)': 
a3.cpp:12: error: invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'char*' 
a3.cpp:12: error:   initializing argument 1 of 'char* strcpy(char*, const char*)' 
a3.cpp: In member function 'void disk::memory(int)': 
a3.cpp:26: error: expected unqualified-id before '=' token 
a3.cpp:28: error: expected primary-expression before '==' token 
a3.cpp: At global scope: 
a3.cpp:37: error: expected initializer before 'mode' 
a3.cpp:42: error: expected initializer before '*' token 
a3.cpp:47: error: expected initializer before 'get_segment'
```

---

```
//a3.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "disk.h"
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstring>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

disk::disk(int num_of_segments, const char* mode)
{
    memory(num_of_segments);
    if(strcmp(mode, "w") || !strcmp(mode, "a"))
        strcpy(mode, mode);

    else
        strcpy(mod, "w");
}   

disk::disk()
{
    memory(20);
    strcpy(mod, "w");
}

void disk::memory(int num)          //private, see header file
{
    segment = new segment[num];
// (nothrow) - page 80 in the text
    if(segment == NULL)
    {
        cerr << "Could not find any data in class ";
        exit(0);
    }
    total = num;
    count = 0;
}

const char* disk::get mode() const
{
    return mode;
}

segment segment* disk::get_all_segment() const
{
    return sgmt;
}

int disk::segment get_segment(int pos) const
{
    segment temp;
    if(pos > 0 && pos < count)
    {
        temp = segment[pos];
    }
    return temp;
}

int disk::get_segment_count() const
{
    return count;
}

disk disk::operator+=(const segment &r)
{
    if(count < total)
    {
        sgmt[count] = r;
        count++;
    }
    return *this;
}

void disk::operator=(const disk &r)
{
    if(*this != &r)
    {
        if(sgmt != NULL)
            delete[] sgmt;
        memory(r.total);
        for(int i=0; i < r.count; i++)
        {
            sgmt[i] = r.sgmt[i];
        }
        count = r.count;
        strcpy(mod, r.mod);
    }
}   

disk::disk(const disk& copy)            //copy constructor
{
    memory(copy.total);
    for(int i=0; i<copy.count; i++)
    {
        sgmt[i] = copy.sgmt[i];
    }
    count = copy.count;
    strcpy(mod, copy.mod);
}

disk::~disk()
{
    if(*sgmt != NULL)
    {
        delete[] sgmt;
    }
}

//disk.h
#include "segment.h"
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstring> class disk {
    private:
        segment *sgmt;
        char mod[3];
        int count, total;
        void memory(int);
    public:
        disk(int, const char *);
        disk( );
        const char* get_mode( ) const;
        segment get_segment(int) const;
        int get_segment_count( ) const;
        const segment* get_all_segments( ) const;
        int access(const char [ ]);
        disk operator+=(const segment &);
        void operator=(const disk &);
        disk(const disk &);
        ~disk( ); };

//segment.h
class segment
{
    private:
        char data[SIZE][41];
    public:
        void initialize(const char [][2000], int);
        void initialize();
        int match(const char []);
        void sort();
        void get_word(char [], int);
        int set_word(const char [], int);
        int set_char(int, int, char);
        char get_char(int, int);
};
```

Comment: `const char *` means "pointer to const char", so you need to recast it to `char*` when passing it to `strcpy`, since `strcpy` wants to write to the memory that the pointer points to. I can't help but wonder why you want to copy a string onto itself though(?).

Comment: Why not just use `std::string`?

Comment: The first error is spelled out for you by the compiler as clearly as it is ever possible. If you don't understand what it means, it is time to go back to reading C++ books. The second and the third error is for the code that simply makes no sense. You have to re-read that code and fix it. Only you can fix the code that makes no sense, since only you know what you were trying to do.

Comment: also, shouldn't you use `<cstdlib>` instead of `<stdlib.h>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to just work through the errors one by one, starting at the top.

The first error is:

```
a3.cpp:12: error: invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'char*' 
a3.cpp:12: error:   initializing argument 1 of 'char* strcpy(char*, const char*)'
```

And the referenced line 12 is:

```
strcpy(mode, mode);
```

You declared `mode` as `const char*` and the error says `strcpy` takes `char*` as its first argument. The error says its invalid to convert `const char*` to `char*`. So it should be clear that the error is that you aren't allowed to pass `mode` as the first argument to `strcpy`.

`strcpy(mode, mode);` makes no sense and is not allowed. `mode` cannot be modified but strcpy will modify it. Furthermore, you are trying to copy it over itself, which, if it worked, would do nothing.

---

AndreyT is right about these last errors; you have to learn to just go back and re-read the code they point at and see what you did wrong.

`segement` in `segment = new segment[num];` is a type name, in which case you can't assign to it like this, or get its value like in `if(segment == NULL)`. You probably mean `sgmt`.

In `const char* disk::get mode() const` you forgot an underscore.

In `segment segment* disk::get_all_segment() const` and `int disk::segment get_segment(int pos) const` you have an extra `segment`s.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing `mode` to `strcpy` but the `const` modifier on `mode` prevents the contents from being modified.  You also have several typos (`mod` vs. `mode`), unless `mod` is defined in a header file somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

The first argument (mode) for `strcpy` should be of type `char*`, not `const char*`

`segment = new segment[num];` is not valid because `segment` is a type. You need a name for the particular segment.
Try something like:

`segment* my_seg = new segment[num];`

Answer (score 0):

At line 12 you pass `mode`, which is a `const char*` as a first argument to `strcpy()`, which expects a `char*`. `strcpy()` will modify the pointed memory so you can not pass a const pointer. By the way that line is almost certainly wrong, why would you want to copy `mode` into itself? It's a no-operation. You probably meant `strcpy(mod, mode)`.

At line 26 and 28 you use `segment` as a variable, but it is a type (`class segment`). You probably meant `sgmt`.

At line 37 you wrote `get mode()` (with *space*) instead of `get_mode()` (with *underscore* _).

At line 42 you wrote `segment segment* disk::get_all_segment() const` instead of `const segment* disk::get_all_segment() const`.

At line 47 you wrote `int disk::segment get_segment(int pos) const`. It should be `segment disk::get_segment(int pos) const`.

In general, the signature is

```
returned_value class_name::function_name(parameters) const
```